# where can i obtain eclipse juno sever adaptor for WAS 8.5 server

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, websphere, eclipse-juno, websphere-portal

I have eclipse juno ide with me.

I need server adaptor for WAS 8.5  version server.

I need steps to add the plugin and also the site from which i can get it.

I have tried using eclipse market place and also from IBM support sites.

Comment: Do you need it for WAS only or do you also need it for WebSphere Portal as you have tagged this with the websphere-portal tag?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for: [WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse Juno & Kepler](https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/downloads/websphere-application-server-developer-tools-v8-5-5/)